# What is python's equivalent of R's NA?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn, data-scrubbing

What is python's equivalent of R's NA?

To be more specific:
R has NaN, NA, NULL, Inf and -Inf. NA is generally used when there is missing data. What is python's equivalent?

How libraries such as numpy and pandas handle missing values?

How does scikit-learn handle missing values?

Is it different for python 2.7 and python 3?

Comment: Probably `None`, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Numpy uses [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html).

Comment: @Makoto `None` is equivalent to `NULL` as far as I know

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scikit-learn doesn't handle missing values currently.
For most machine learning algorithms, it is unclear how to handle missing values, and so we rely on the user of handling them prior to giving them to the algorithm.
Numpy doesn't have a "missing" value. Pandas uses NaN, but inside numeric algorithms that might lead to confusion. It is possible to use masked arrays, but we don't do that in scikit-learn (yet).

Comment: NaN in Pandas is numpy's nan value.

Answer (score 29):

`nan` in numpy is handled well with many functions:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [1, np.nan, 2, 3]
>>> np.nanmean(a)
2.0
>>> np.nansum(a)
6.0
>>> np.isnan(a)
array([False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 8):

for `pandas` take a look at this.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html

pandas uses `NaN`. You can test for null values using `isnull()` or `not null()`, drop them from a data frame using `dropna()` etc. The equivalent for `datetime` objects is `NaT`

Comment: It might be worth noting that integer pandas `Series` (or column) must have values.  There is no way to represent a missing value in an integer series; the usual alternative being to upconvert to a floating point type that has `NaN`.